# Why output is 6 instead of other numbers?

Tags: c#, list, lambda

```
List<int> lista = new List<int>() { 3, 4, 9, 8, 5, 6, 0, 3, 8, 3 };
int number = lista.Count(n => n <= 5);
```

I understand that we create list with those numbers... but how we get 6? dont understand actually what happend with (n => n <= 5) this.

Comment: i am learning  c#

Comment: A lot of languages are covered on this site, so a tag is needed (which I added).

Comment: The lambda counts the numbers less than or equal to 5.  Six numbers qualify.

Comment: If you want to get others numbers based on your condition you should change the line " int number = lista.Count(n => n <= 5); " and use " List<int> numbers = lista.Where(n => n <= 5).ToList(); ", then you'll got a list of numbers instead of a count. I hope this help you

Answer (score 20):

This is counting the number of elements within the list where the number is less than or equal to 5. You get "6" because the elements 3, 4, 5, 0, 3, and 3 meet this criteria.

The `n => n <= 5` can be confusing. It is a combination of lamba expression (`n =>`*expression*) and the predicate/condition (`n <= 5`).

When you call this `Count<TSource>(...)` method, you are calling an extension method from Enumerable with this signature:

```
Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
```

For your case, the `source` is "lista", and your `predicate` is the condition of `n <= 5`. Then, basically this code is running:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (TSource element in source) {
    checked {
        if (predicate(element)) count++;
    }
}
return count;
```

This is how it iterates over your list counting only if the predicate condition matches what you provided.

Full Source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,1329

Answer (score 4):

Because there are 6 elements 3, 4, 5, 0, 3, 3 which are less than or equal to 5.

You mentioned that you are learning c# so let me be more crystal clear.

```
int number = lista.Count(n => n <= 5);
```

In that part let's start by first **n**, this says let every item of list be **n** and  **=>** means i point a condition about n. And **n <= 5** part is your condition. This is called **Lambda expression**. And typing that lambda expression as parameter of Count() method will give you the count that meets your condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> lista = new List<int>() { 3, 4, 9, 8, 5, 6, 0, 3, 8, 3 };

int number = lista.Count(n => n <= 5);  // will be 6 and elements are {3,4,5,0,3,3}

var list  =  lista.Where(n => n <= 5).ToList(); // to check what elements in list after applying <= 5

    foreach(int n in list)
    {
        Console.Write(n+",");
        //output is 3,4,5,0,3,3,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is the translated of your Lambda expression (n => n <= 5) in traditional way:

```
List<int> lista = new List<int>() { 3, 4, 9, 8, 5, 6, 0, 3, 8, 3 };
// int number = lista.Count(n => n <= 5);
List<int> listb = new List<int>();

foreach(int n in lista)
{
    if (n <= 5)
        listb.Add(n);
}
int number = listb.Count();
```